# incremental loads from blob storage to azure table storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a following scenario. (A rather common one but I am not entirely sure where to start)

I have data incoming into blob storage container (our raw zone). The files get dropped in raw zone everyday(by someone sitting somewhere). Each day as the new files come in, the old files are overwritten, but the number of records increases.

Suppose a customer file from yesterday may have 100 records, today's file might have 150 records. (100 from yesterday and 50 from today).

Now, what is the best way to do an incremental load (or other solutions welcome) for moving latest number of records into the azure table storage.

I have worked with using watermarks etc when loading data from or into sql, but don't have so much experience with Azure table. Would appreciate if I can get a lead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADF to do incremental load into Azure Table Storage using watermarks. Refer to below links and you might need to tweak the implementation a little based on requirements.

[Incrementally load data from Azure SQL Database to Azure Blob storage using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-portal)

[Copy data to and from Azure Table storage using Azure Data Factory or Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage?tabs=data-factory)